# Primefaces 4.0 not working with IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, internet-explorer-11

I got a project with Primefaces 4.0 and JSF 2.1
So when I test it in Chrome, Firefox or IE10 it works but when I try it it IE 11; it doesn´t work fine.
If I select a record and open it on a dialog; i does not show data to edit.
Also if I use charts; in IE11, they are not showed.

Why is primefaces 4.0 not working on IE11??

Thanks in advance

Comment: check http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6658

Comment: and how do you update the jquery version?

Comment: open the jar and check /META-INF/resources/primefaces/jquery/

Comment: There are easier ways than fiddling with JARs, Leo.

Comment: like what??? I was thinking on migrating to Primefaces 5.0, but I´m a little dubious whether it will solve the problem.